# How to assign row changes to an existing matrix within an 'apply' function from the parallel package

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing, assign, mclapply

In R one can use the `<<-` symbol within the `lapply()` function to assign a value to a variable outside `lapply()`.

Let's consider a matrix full of 1:

```
m<-matrix(data=1, nrow=5, ncol=5)
```

Let's say I want to replace each row by the values 1,2,3,4 and 5 using the assignation symbol `<<-`. I can use the function the lapply function (it is not the designed function for that kind of operation, this is only an example):

```
lapply(X = seq(nrow(m)), FUN = function(r){
  m[r,]<<-seq(5)
})
```

This will work.

But if I now use mclapply like this:

```
mclapply(X = seq(nrow(m)), FUN = function(r){
  m[r,]<<-seq(5)
})
```

The matrix m will remain full of 1.

The idea is to apply changes to rows of a matrix, without creating a new one, but rather assigning them in the existing one. The only constrain is to use a function from the parallel package (e.g. mclapply(), but maybe another function would better fit).
Also using the `<<-` symbol is not mandatory.
How can I do that ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot do this kind of in-place assignment when in parallel.

Comment: Trying to modify an object from several processes at the same time seems pretty risky. Are all the operation necessarily on different rows? Can't there be a collision with two processes trying to access the same values? (in your general use, not you example)

Comment: @Axeman that's what I am afraid of... but I prefer to ask first since, even doing it in parallel it refers to specific rows.

Comment: @Gallarus I don't see the kind of collision you are wondering about. I would assume that parallel processing a matrix on its rows, would actually somehow "split" the tasks to always be specific to the set of rows to replace. the structure of the matrix (number of rows and columns) doesn't change. Only the content changes.

Comment: @YoannPageaud in your example yes. I was wondering if you were envisioning the possibility to expand your approach to more general problems where this could happen. Because right now your example does not really justify all this complexity so I figure you had something more elaborate in mind.

Comment: @Gallarus the example is a simple version of row replacement I want to do. But the idea remains the same: replacing rows without recreating a new matrix, just assign the new values to the row of interest. Iterating on rows, in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign in parallel, as you're just assigning to a local copy of the matrix.

Two solutions:

1. Use shared memory (e.g. matrices on disk using package {bigstatsr}; disclaimer: I'm the author)
2. Don't assign in the first place. Just run the `lapply()`, get all the results parts as a list and use `do.call("rbind", list)`.

Comment: I will wait few more days, just in case and I think I will just accept that it is not possible to assign in parallel.  
Your package looks very interesting, I will keep it in mind : how is it in term of speed ? have you done some benchmark to compare how much time your functions takes compare to matrix in RAM ? 
I am wondering if keeping the result in a list before running `do.call()` doesn't risk to use more memory than keeping values in a matrix.

Comment: Assigning to a matrix will take no time as compared to the actual computation you perform in parallel. Having a list then a matrix will require twice as much memory indeed.

Comment: Does your package take in account the type of 'disk' used (does it work using a SSD ? should I use a SSD or an HDD) ?

Comment: I think we should stay in touch: I am currently developping a package for visualizations in genomics using ggplot2 and I think this idea of matrices on disk is also relevant for my work and could be an added value to my package.

I am also encountering some difficulties manipulating matrices (because reshape2 is deprecated and I don't want to move to tidyr because then my package would depend on too many dependencies, would be super heavy for no reason...) maybe if you have functions such as cast() and melt() that would be super convenient for me. Wanna discuss that on Twitter ?

Comment: Sure, or by email.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using the [future package](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future)

```
library(future)
plan(multiprocess) 

m <- matrix(data = 1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

# we create a set of futures, so the values are calculated in parallele and
# not sent back to the main environment
fs <- lapply(seq(nrow(m)), function(x) future(seq(5) + x))

# when then pull the values one by one and apply them where they belong
for (i in seq(nrow(m))) {
  m[i, ] <- value(fs[[i]])
}

# or the same way you did it:
lapply(X = seq(nrow(m)), FUN = function(r){
  m[r,] <<- value(fs[[r]]) 
})
```

The drawback here is that the value are assigned sequentially but at least they are calculated in parallel. But, I don't think you intend to use the matrix before all calculations are done anyway.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about using the future package.
It would have been a great idea.
The thing is I am currently developping a package and try to reduce the number of dependencies as much as possible to keep it 'light': currently I use the parallel package as one of the dependencies, so if I can just rely on a unique package for all parallel stuff it is better.
But the future option would have totally fit the problem without this constrain.
Once I will release my package I will definitely consider making use of future rather than parallel in the next versions.

Comment: Using `future` has the added value of making your package work in parallel easily on multiple OSes. And it has low dependencies itself. But I understand your concern.